# Get Webpage HTML in network restricted with PROXY Server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using following function to get the HTML string of the webpage with URL url.

```
   function GetWebPageHTML() {
       $.ajax({
           url: webpageURL,
           type: "GET",
           success: function (data) {
               alert('success');
           },
           error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
               alert(errorThrown + '\n' + status + '\n' + xhr.statusText);
           }
       });
   }
```

The code gets executed when it runs on my personal internet but the same code throw error when this code runs in my office internet environment. The reason may be that in my office we use Proxy Server. Am I right? If I am right , then how can I use Proxy Server URL in my code so that I can get the webpage HTML in all environment?

Comment: If your company uses websense and your domain is listed in the blocked category..then..bad luck buddy..

Comment: If it is the proxy then your office it blocks the visit of the ajax script. Since ajax just uses http traffic i highly doubt that.

Answer (score 0):

If the browser is configured to use a proxy server, then it will use it automatically and you don't need to do anything special with JS to make it so.

If you don't like the browser's configuration, then there is no way for JavaScript (running in a webpage) to reconfigure the user's browser to use a proxy server (or a different proxy server or no proxy server).